# How to update CentOS packages with dependencies without access to a repository

Tags: linux, centos, package, rpm, yum

I have a CentOS 6.9 Linux VM with access to repository disabled, i.e. file `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` is deleted so to prevent accidental updates of the packages because we need a set of specific versions.

So I'm trying to update just the necessary packages. I have `pacemaker-cli-1.1.15-5.el6` installed and I want to update it to `pacemaker-cli-1.1.18-3.el6`. Its dependency is `pacemaker-libs-1.1.15-5.el6` . So I tried the following command

```
sudo yum localinstall http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/pacemaker-libs-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64.rpm http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/pacemaker-cli-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
```

But I got the following errors:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities
Setting up Local Package Process
pacemaker-libs-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                               | 578 kB     00:00
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-xFPI0g/pacemaker-libs-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64.rpm: pacemaker-libs-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-xFPI0g/pacemaker-libs-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64.rpm as an update to pacemaker-libs-1.1.15-5.el6.x86_64
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
pacemaker-cli-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                | 312 kB     00:00
Examining /var/tmp/yum-root-xFPI0g/pacemaker-cli-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64.rpm: pacemaker-cli-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64
Marking /var/tmp/yum-root-xFPI0g/pacemaker-cli-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64.rpm as an update to pacemaker-cli-1.1.15-5.el6.x86_64
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package pacemaker-cli.x86_64 0:1.1.15-5.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: pacemaker-cli = 1.1.15-5.el6 for package: pacemaker-1.1.15-5.el6.x86_64
---> Package pacemaker-cli.x86_64 0:1.1.18-3.el6 will be an update
---> Package pacemaker-libs.x86_64 0:1.1.15-5.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: pacemaker-libs = 1.1.15-5.el6 for package: pacemaker-1.1.15-5.el6.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pacemaker-libs = 1.1.15-5.el6 for package: pacemaker-cluster-libs-1.1.15-5.el6.x86_64
---> Package pacemaker-libs.x86_64 0:1.1.18-3.el6 will be an update
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: pacemaker-1.1.15-5.el6.x86_64 (@scalearc-3.2)
           Requires: pacemaker-libs = 1.1.15-5.el6
           Removing: pacemaker-libs-1.1.15-5.el6.x86_64 (@scalearc-3.2)
               pacemaker-libs = 1.1.15-5.el6
           Updated By: pacemaker-libs-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64 (/pacemaker-libs-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64)
               pacemaker-libs = 1.1.18-3.el6
Error: Package: pacemaker-1.1.15-5.el6.x86_64 (@scalearc-3.2)
           Requires: pacemaker-cli = 1.1.15-5.el6
           Removing: pacemaker-cli-1.1.15-5.el6.x86_64 (@scalearc-3.2)
               pacemaker-cli = 1.1.15-5.el6
           Updated By: pacemaker-cli-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64 (/pacemaker-cli-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64)
               pacemaker-cli = 1.1.18-3.el6
Error: Package: pacemaker-cluster-libs-1.1.15-5.el6.x86_64 (@scalearc-3.2)
           Requires: pacemaker-libs = 1.1.15-5.el6
           Removing: pacemaker-libs-1.1.15-5.el6.x86_64 (@scalearc-3.2)
               pacemaker-libs = 1.1.15-5.el6
           Updated By: pacemaker-libs-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64 (/pacemaker-libs-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64)
               pacemaker-libs = 1.1.18-3.el6
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Could you help?

Comment: This is off topic here as its not a *programming* related question, its a setup/config issue. You should delete this / migrate it over to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com) where someone will be able to assist.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently the error happens because not all the dependencies are listed in the command. All 4 `pacemaker` components have to be updated at once and the command that does this is:

```
sudo yum install http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/pacemaker-libs-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64.rpm http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/pacemaker-cli-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64.rpm http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/pacemaker-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64.rpm http://mirror.centos.org/centos/6/os/x86_64/Packages/pacemaker-cluster-libs-1.1.18-3.el6.x86_64.rpm
```